# update each row with different values in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column that I need to update with codes in a temp table.There is +/- 5 codes in the temp table. Each row in the table must be updated with one of the values in the temp table.

```
Example
id  code
1   200
2   400
3   600
4   9000
5   800
6   200
7   400
8   600
9   9000
10  800
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  And how do you decide what code goes where?   Does it matter?

Comment: Show us your temp table. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: you should provide some more information to let us help you better

Comment: yes, i've tried a few things. and no it doesn't matter each code must just go in that order to all the id's in the table.

Comment: yes, i've tried a few things. and no it doesn't matter each code must just go in that order to all the id's in the table.

Comment: UPDATE epm
SET  epm.PaypointAdvisor = 'this is were im not sure'
FROM employer.EmployerPayMethod epm
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM #paypiontadvisorallocationpmid temp WHERE EPM.EmployerPayMethodId = temp.TEmployerPayMethodId )

Comment: So this is Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SQL Server Solution

This query will sequentially take the values from the `temp` table and update the code in the example table in round robin fashion, repeating the values from `temp` when required.

```
update e
set code = t.code
from example e
join temp t on t.id = (e.id -1) % (select count(*) from temp) + 1
```

If the ids are not sequential in either table, then you can `row_number()` them first, e.g.

```
update e
set code = t.code
from (select *,rn=row_number() over (order by id) from example) e
join (select *,rn=row_number() over (order by id) from temp) t
  on t.rn = (e.rn -1) % (select count(*) from temp) + 1
```

The same technique (mod, row-number) can be used in other RDBMS, but the syntax will differ a little.

Answer (score 1):

To get rowset you need try this

```
declare @cnt int

select @cnt = count(*) from codes

select M.id, C.Code
from
(
    select
        T.id, (row_number() over (order by id) - 1) % @cnt + 1 as RowNum
    from T as T
) as M
    left outer join
    (select Code, row_number() over (order by Code) as RowNum from codes as T) as C
        on C.RowNum = M.RowNum
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbd84/1

Answer (score 0):

A Different Approach:
Lets say the table that you want to Update is called Example.
A simple Oracle Merge would be.

```
Merge INTO Example Using Temp_Table ON Example.Id = Temp_Table.Id
When Matched Then
UPDATE Example
SET Example.code = Temp_Table.code
From Example
Inner Join
Temp_Table
ON
Example.Id = Temp_Table.Id
When Not Matched Then
Insert Into Example 
Select * From Temp_Table
```